# CakePHP 3.0: Response as json

Tags: php, json, cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-3.x

I'm creating a CakePHP 3.0 REST API. I followed [this instructions (routing in the book)](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing) and received response in json. Here is my code.

**01 src/config/rout.php**

```
Router::extensions('json');
```

**02 src/controler/UsersController.php**

```
  public function view($id = null) {
    $data = array('status' => 'o','status_message' => 'ok' );
    $this->set('data', $data);
    $this->set('_serialize', 'data');  
}
```

**03 send a post request to this URL**

> http://domain.com/users/view.json

output:

```
{
    "status": "o",
    "status_message": "ok"
}
```

But I want to get json out put without **.json** extension. thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to use `Router::parseExtensions('json');` instead of `Router::extensions('json');` ?

Comment: But, [3-0-migration-guide says](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html) Router::parseExtensions() has been removed. Use Cake\Routing\Router::extensions() instead. This method must be called before routes are connected. It won’t modify existing routes.

Comment: @Maraboc Any way I don't want to add extension for my URL. I want to out put JSON response without .json extension.

Comment: You need to pass header like `Accept: application/json` and you will get the output as json format.

Answer (score 5):

I had same situation but now I found solution for this. Now I can put request url without .json and can get Json data in response as well.

In App controller add network response which will handle your response.

**use Cake\Network\Response;**

After that you need to **convert Json input in array**, So put this `getJsonInput()` function in your `AppController` and call it in `initialize()`

```
public function getJsonInput() {
        $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $this->data = (isset($data) && $data != '') ? json_decode($data, true) : array();
    }
```

Now in your controller, You have all post data in `$this->data`. so you can access all inputs.
Here is an example :

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function index() {

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            //pr($this->data);    //here is your all inputs
           $this->message = 'success';
           $this->status = true;
        }
        $this->respond();
    }
}
```

Now at the end of your function you need to call `respond()` which is defined in `AppController`

```
public function respond() {  
        $this->response->type('json');  // this will convert your response to json
        $this->response->body([
                    'status' => $this->status,
                    'code' => $this->code,
                    'responseData' => $this->responseData,
                    'message'=> $this->message,
                    'errors'=> $this->errors,
                ]);   // Set your response in body
        $this->response->send();  // It will send your response
        $this->response->stop();  // At the end stop the response
    }
```

Define all variable in the `AppController` as

```
public $status = false;
public $message = '';
public $responseData = array();
public $code = 200;
public $errors = '';
```

One more thing to do is:

In the `Response.php (/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Network/Response.php)` 
You need to edit one line at 586 
`echo $content;` to `echo json_encode($content);` in  `_sendContent()` function.

That's it. Now you can set request url as 
`domain_name/project_name/users/index`.

Answer (score 1):

If someone still looking for easy json response solution here is a quick one :

add this method to your AppController.php

```
public function jsonResponse($responseData = [], $responseStatusCode = 200) {

    Configure::write('debug', 0);

    $this->response->type('json');
    $this->response->statusCode($responseStatusCode);
    $this->response->body(json_encode($responseData));
    $this->response->send();
    $this->render(false,false);

}
```

and you can use it in any action as simple as that

```
$data = ['status' => 'ok', 'foo' => 'bar'];
$this->jsonResponse($data);
```

and another example

```
$data = ['status' => 'failed', 'bar' => 'foo'];
$this->jsonResponse($data, 404);
```

hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Request your data with a [proper HTTP accept header](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31212/difference-between-the-accept-and-content-type-http-headers)  `Accept: application/json`, the RequestHandler should pick it up then.

> The Accept header is used by HTTP clients to tell the server what
>   content types they'll accept. The server will then send back a
>   response, which will include a Content-Type header telling the client
>   what the content type of the returned content actually is.
>
> However, as you may have noticed, HTTP requests can also contain
>   Content-Type headers. Why? Well, think about POST or PUT requests.
>   With those request types, the client is actually sending a bunch of
>   data to the server as part of the request, and the Content-Type header
>   tells the server what the data actually is (and thus determines how
>   the server will parse it).
>
> In particular, for a typical POST request resulting from an HTML form
>   submission, the Content-Type of the request will normally be either
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data.